# how to get mysql id of number of effect row

Tags: php, mysql

I perform the mysql query to check if any number of row effected on the user input data with the help of `mysql_num_rows($query)`. Only one row will effect always as I made some rows are unique. If one row effect, I want to get the ID of that Row. I means the auto increment ID of the same row.

The same row contains many fields, its better if I come to know how to get the entry of other fields.

Thanks stack for your solutions.

Comment: Why don't you just fetch that row?

Comment: I'm sorry but the description confuses me a bit. Are you looking for the `ID` of the row affected by an `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. You have an `id` column, and have other fields that are unique (UNIQUE constraint on [column2,column3,column4], and want to get the `id` based on the other unique columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `SELECT id FROM table WHERE value=condition`? If you query that you will get the id of the row that matches your condition. Replace id with the identifactor row, table with your table name, value and condition with your conditions.

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE value=condition";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  //$row contains valid information.
}
```

Btw: don´t use mysql_* anymore, its deprecated, look at PDO or mysqli_*

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT mysql_id
          FROM table";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$id = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

You'll probably have to add a "WHERE" clause to your query statement and then pass the values into in array using a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

just use `mysql_insert_id();`
 this function after executing the insert query.

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES ('test')";
 mysql_query( $query );
 $lastInsertId=mysql_insert_id();
 echo $lastInsertId;
```